# Problems aligning button on timeline with CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to align the two buttons on the middle line and also align the white balls on the line, I've tried using position with CSS but I didn't succeed, I'm not good at design, and I also don't know how to be responsive on all devices
Could someone please help me? I don't know what to do to adjust this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the best approach, but could be considered as an option

Try modifying the left value of the following:

```
.tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list:before {
   left: 50.5% // was 46%
}
```

This would fix your issue until the screen size gets lower than 500px. You might have to change the left value again for the lower screen sizes.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .mytabs_area {
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #766dff 0%, #88f3ff 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #766dff 0%, #88f3ff 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #766dff 0%, #88f3ff 100%);
        }

        .p_120 {
            padding-top: 120px;
            padding-bottom: 120px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 575px) {
            .p_120 {
                padding-top: 70px;
                padding-bottom: 70px;
            }
        }

        .tabs_inner .nav.nav-tabs {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            border: none;
            margin-bottom: 120px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .nav.nav-tabs li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 8px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .nav.nav-tabs li a {
            margin: 0px;
            line-height: 50px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 0px 40px;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid #9ab5f5;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        }

        .tabs_inner .nav.nav-tabs li a.active {
            background: #fff;
            color: #222222;
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list {
            max-width: 460px;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 60px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list:before {
            content: "";
            height: 100%;
            width: 5px;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            position: absolute;
            left: 46%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            top: -5px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li {
            margin-bottom: 60px;
            position: relative;
        }

 .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li span {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    position: relative;
    left: 8.6rem;
    top: 2.1rem;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li span:before {
            content: '';
            height: 7px;
            width: 7px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 52%;
            top: 4px;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li .media .d-flex {
            padding-right: 100px;
        }

       .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li .media .d-flex p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: 2rem;
}

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li .media .media-body h4 {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 21px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li .media .media-body p {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li .media .media-body h4 {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 21px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .tabs_inner .tab-content .tab-pane .list li .media .d-flex p {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <section class="mytabs_area p_120">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tabs_inner">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">My Experiences</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">My Education</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li>
                                <span></span>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <p>March 2017 to present</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Colorlib</h4>
                                        <p>Senior Web Developer <br />Santa monica, Los angeles</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span></span>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <p>March 2017 to present</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Colorlib</h4>
                                        <p>Senior Web Developer <br />Santa monica, Los angeles</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span></span>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <p>March 2017 to present</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Colorlib</h4>
                                        <p>Senior Web Developer <br />Santa monica, Los angeles</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li>
                                <span></span>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <p>March 2017 to present</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Colorlib</h4>
                                        <p>Senior Web Developer <br />Santa monica, Los angeles</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span></span>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <p>March 2017 to present</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Colorlib</h4>
                                        <p>Senior Web Developer <br />Santa monica, Los angeles</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span></span>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <p>March 2017 to present</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Colorlib</h4>
                                        <p>Senior Web Developer <br />Santa monica, Los angeles</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Code updated: Just swap with yours.

Explanation:

I have changed the position of the text and the white button to relative and replace it on aligned form.